# Is it possible to protect a file in c?

Tags: c

I have written a password program in c. and I saved the password in a text file using some encryptiion and retrieving the old password from a file using decryption techniques So that user cannot see the password.Yes ofcourse this might not be the efficient way to do because there is a chance for user to delete the text file.

But still I want to lock (protect) a file using my c password code.I have searched on google I found perl can be used to lock a file.The question is that possible in c? Do we have any function like flock in perl? or suggest me some functions that can be helpful to develop a file lock function in c.becuase People may say we have c# and lots of stuff out to lock a file and why your sticking to c? but I like challenging the things.So please let me know If theres something I need to learn.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Three different questions merged into one: 1) Can a file be locked 2) Can a file be transparently encrypted by providing a key 3) Can an application be called when a file is accessed, in order to decrypt it.  Please clarify the question.

Comment: Thats not my real question Read it again steve.I want to set a password to a file and lock it.And to reopen it.We have to re-enter the password.And the entered password is saved  in a txt file using c file concepts and i have encrypted the password so that users cannot see the password.Got the point?

Comment: but are you after the OS to prompt for the password or is this all implemented in your own APIs?  This matches both #2 and #3 in my list.

Comment: Steve-o is right. What do you want the function you are looking for todo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, on a POSIX system, use `fcntl()` along with the `F_SETLK` value for the command argument, and then set `F_WRLCK` (i.e, and exclusive lock) in the `struct flock` data-member `l_type`.

So for instance (add your own error-detection mechanisms):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct flock fl;
int file_descriptor;
int file_length;

fd = open("my_password_file", O_RDWR);

//... get the length of the file and set the variable file_length

fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;
fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
fl.l_start = 0;
fl.l_len = file_length;

//set the exclusive-lock on the file
fcntl(fd, F_SETLK, &fl);
```

Comment: Well im going throught the fcnt1() on google but is it possible to set a password to it?

Comment: @niko see my post. flock and fcntl are not here to control access to a file like the windows ACL for instance. It is here to provide some kind of exclusiveness DURING some kind of operation. With file locking you can specify that your process is the only one allowed to access the file WHILE it is running. All locks are freed once your program terminate. Acess control, as you need it, is part of the operating system (ACLs, read/ write permissions)

Answer (score 1):

http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock

What do you want to achieve with `flock`? `flock` or any other kind of file locking will not prevent the user from deleting the file. He may not be able to do it while your program is running, but once your program terminates, all locks are freed.

flock is used to gain some kind of exclusiveness for accessing a file during some kind of I/O operation.

hth

Mario

Answer (score 0):

On Windows I could use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653) or [Handle](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) to close the handle out from under your program. So even if you could do it, someone else could undo it.